# problem with the dynamic composition of a grid

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, grid

I have an asynchronous function in c # that returns me a scrollView in which a Grid composed with two static columns is created inside it and the Row is dynamically created inside a For.
If inside the For I create only one Row at a time then the result is correct but if inside it I try to create two Row at a time the Grid is composed in the wrong way without any logical sense.

the first Row in the code is populated with a Label in column 0, and a Button in column 1 and with and the rows are assigned by the variable "p" which is incremented at the end of the For.
in the second Row instead I would like to insert a simple label without text with a black background
this Row is also dynamically assigned by the variable "p + 1".

it is as if it completely ignores the content that I want to assign to the second Row by assigning it to the last row created during the loop, the second screen clarifies that

I am attaching the simplified code

```
 public async Task<Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView> GridComposionAsync()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView scrollView = new Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView();
        scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical;

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        
        grid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.7 , GridUnitType.Star)  });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star) }); 
         

         int p = 0;
         int ts = Tempo / 10;

         for (int i = 0; i < 144; i += 0)
         {
             bool st = false;

  // in this part of the code checks are carried out for which the variable st can be true or false
                     
                 if (st == true)
                 {

                    // create first Row 

                   Label label = new Label
                   {
                         Text = $"è la riga n :{x.arrPre[i].Orario}" + "stato : " + st,
                         BackgroundColor = Color.Blue
                     };

                   Button button = new Button
                     {
                         Text = $"Button:{p}",
                         BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                       
                     };
                   button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;
                
              
                   grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 100 });
                   grid.Children.Add(label, 0, p);
                   grid.Children.Add(button, 1, p);

                  // create Second Row

                   grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 10 });
                   Label label2row = new Label { BackgroundColor = Color.Black };
                   grid.Children.Add(label2row, 0, p + 1);

                   p++;
                   i += ts;
                 }
                 else
                 {                      
                     i++;
                 }
             }
         }));
        scrollView.Content = grid;
        return scrollView;  
    }
```

this is the screen of my result ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/34teL.png

second screen ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4zvG.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're inserting two rows every time, you should to plus `2` for each `p`.

I don't know what `ts` does in your code, so I'm just going to insert two lines at a time, and you can change it if you want.

```
public async Task<Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView> GridComposionAsync()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView scrollView = new Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView();
        scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical;

        Grid grid = new Grid();

        grid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.7, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star) });


        int p = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ )
        {
            bool st = true;

            // in this part of the code checks are carried out for which the variable st can be true or false

            if (st == true)
            {

                // create first Row 

                Label label = new Label
                {
                    Text = $"è la riga n : {i}" + "stato : " + st,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Blue
                };

                Button button = new Button
                {
                    Text = $"Button:{i}",
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,

                };
                button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;


                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 100 });
                grid.Children.Add(label, 0, p);
                grid.Children.Add(button, 1, p);

            

                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 10 });
                Label label2row = new Label { BackgroundColor = Color.Black };
                grid.Children.Add(label2row, 0, p+1);
                p+=2;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        scrollView.Content = grid;
        return scrollView;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much !!  that careless, I had not completely noticed, thanks again 